# MariaDB start err

Tags: mysql, mariadb

[image: image of error logs]

active status of maria db is failed, but I'm using maria db service (CRUD)

what is that problem?

Comment: please to give more information, your point is problem on server service, if your OS is ubuntu or there family you can search to /var/log and find mariaDB folder and show to public the log

Answer (score 0):

The systemd status output only shows the last few lines of the error messages, but the actual error must have been a few lines further up.

Can you try `journalctl -r -u mariadb.service` and show the output of that?